# Login with Twitter for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter, authentication

I'm searching for some docs or examples on CakePHP and logging in with Twitter. I found on the Bakery a Facebook Connect tutorial (which looks dead easy) but not much on Twitter.

Has anyone come across any such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these Twitter models:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rynop/2010/08/29/twitter-model-plus-plus-for-the-twitter-datasource

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1077/An-Example